# C++ how to know what type of member does a class has in C++

Tags: c++

I know that there is no reflection in C++ like in Java, C# and AS3. But I really need to know what type of member a class has. (I suppose a user creates a class in a way I can provide him, and then I should be able to list all member types.) How can I do that?

Of course, I can add a pre-processing phase on the natural pre-processingto accomplish this, but I want another solution. More elegant and not hacky.

Example:

User creates a class like this: (the way of creation a class can we in a different way, for example I can require inheritance from some class or using a macro...)

```
class A
{
   int a;
   double b;
};
```

And now I can get a list of all members of class `A` {"int", "double"} as strings list. like this, for example:

```
GetTypes::listOfMemberTypes(A) or GetTypes<A>::listOfMemberTypes
```

returns list that contains "int", "double"

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: So your question is "I know this is not possible within the language, and I know I can do it outside the language instead, but how can I do it within the language? Really? Programming does not work on the basis of "pretty please". C++ will not spontaneously grow a reflection feature just because you "really need it".

Comment: jalt this kind of slogans are just popular and nothing else. Is there a way to determine if it is an object or an enum? Yes it is, and this is not a language built in, see boost::is_enum

Comment: @Narek `boost::is_enum` works with compiler intrinsics, and it actually became part of the language in C++11.

Comment: Before C++11 we had boost::is_enum as a new feature created by developers. Here I ask the same: language does not provide, but may be we can create??

Comment: @Narek: Sure, boost:is_enum and other type traits can tell you some information about a type at compile-time. But (1) it can't tell you which members a class has, and (2) it requires you to compile the code yourself, and you didn't specify in your question if that was acceptable (you talk about "users", and users typically see your compiled program, not the source code), and you talk about reflection, which is typically understood to be a run time mechanism, rather than a compile time one.

Comment: jalf thank you, but you really did not understand the question. When I talk about users, I talk about other programmers that will use the code (framework) I have created.

Comment: I wanted to create something like Artemis Entity System Framework. This is the reason of my question.

Answer (score 6):

You read the source code for the class in question.

Comment: +1. One way to do this would be to employ an existing compiler; Clang provides [LibClang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) for such uses.

Comment: jalf, for humor 100 out of 100, as for technical answer 0. ;)

Comment: At least I have a proposal in this topic: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3883.html

Comment: @Narek I was not being funny. This answer is technically accurate. You can read the the source code yourself, or parse it with a tool like LibClang, or you can use type traits or similar to "read" it in code, *but you need to have access to the source code*. I'm sorry that it doesn't let you do what you want, but that is just how C++ works.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way to do this in C++, as you said. However, if you are willing to go for solutions which are not cross-platform, it may be possible to use debugging symbols to do this. For example, if the application is compiled by GCC with "-g" (or you are able to get a copy of the binary compiled with this option), you might be able to inspect the debugging symbols that have been compiled into the binary. For doing this, I would suggest taking a look at the source code of GDB.

Comment: No debugging symbols, definitely are not the solution I look for.

Answer (score 0):

You may require that `A` is a `std::tuple`, so you have the list of type at compile type.

You may then create a function to build the list of names (with `typeid(T).name()`).

Something like:

```
namespace detail {

template <typename T> struct tuple_name;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct tuple_name<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr std::array<std::string, sizeof...(Ts)> get_names()
    {
        return { typeid(Ts).name()... };
    }
};

} // namespace detail

template <typename T>
static constexpr auto get_names()
-> decltype(detail::tuple_name<T>::get_names())
{
    return detail::tuple_name<T>::get_names();
}
```

So test it:

```
class C{};

typedef std::tuple<int, char, C> UserType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (const auto& name : get_names<UserType>())
        std::cout << name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How it can be done? Please be more specific (example?).

Comment: @Narek: Added a sample.

Comment: In this code you don't have a user defined class, you have a user defined instance of a datastructure.